# Easy/Simple way to write switch-like regular expressions

Tags: python

I'm newbie for Python and wondering what is best way to write a code below in perl into python:

```
if ($line =~ /(\d)/) {
   $a = $1
}
elsif ($line =~ /(\d\d)/) {
   $b = $1
}
elsif ($line =~ /(\d\d\d)/) {
   $c = $1
}
```

What I want to do is to retrieve a specific part of each line within a large set of lines. In python all what I can do is as below and is very ugly.

```
res = re.search(r'(\d)', line)
if res:
  a = res.group(1)
else:
  res = re.search(r'(\d\d)', line)
  if res:
    b = res.group(1)
  else:
    res = re.search(r'(\d\d\d)', line)
    if res:
      c = res.group(1)
```

Does any one know better way to write same thing without non-built-in module?

**EDIT:**

How do you write if you need parse line using very different re?
My point here is it should be simple so that any one can understand what the code is doing there.
In perl, we can write:

```
if ($line =~ /^this is a sample line (.+) and contain single value$/) {
  $name = $1
}
elsif ($line =~ /^this is another sample: (.+):(.+) two values here$/) {
  ($address, $call) = ($1, $2)
}
elsif ($line =~ /^ahhhh thiiiss isiss (\d+) last sample line$/) {
  $description = $1
}
```

From my view, this kind perl code is very simple and easy to understand.

**EDIT2:**
I found same discussion here:

http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/750203-checking-string-against-multiple-patterns

So there's no way to write in python simple enough like perl..

Comment: you could use `elif`

Comment: Can you share for which value of $line, elsif section will be executed? IMO, only 'if ($line =~ /(\d)/)' is sufficient for all cases; unless conditions are in reverse order.

Comment: Are you giving a default value if a b or c don't match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write yourself a helper function to store the result of the match at an outer scope so that you don't need to rematch the regex in the if statement

```
def search(patt, str): 
    search.result = re.search(patt, str)
    return search.result

if search(r'(\d)', line):
    a = search.result.group(1)
elif search(r'(\d\d)', line):
    b = search.result.group(1)
elif search(r'(\d\d\d)', line):
    c = search.result.group(1)
```

---

In python 3.8, you'll be able to use:

```
if res := re.search(r'(\d)', line):
    a = res.group(1)
elif res := re.search(r'(\d\d)', line):
    b = res.group(1)
elif res := re.search(r'(\d\d\d)', line):
    c = res.group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Order** of the pattern is very important. Because if you use this `(\d)|(\d\d)|(\d\d\d)` pattern, the first group alone will match all the digit characters. So, it won't try to check the next two patterns, since the first pattern alone will find all the matches.

```
res = re.search(r'(\d\d\d)|(\d\d)|(\d)', line)
if res:
    a, b, c = res.group(3), res.group(2), res.group(1)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eV8hK5/1)

Comment: Yeap you are right...but how can we know the order in general?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor simple, first capturing group refers the index 1. So you could get the values captured by `(\d\d\d)` group from `res.group(1)`

Comment: No I meant which regex to use first in the |?

Comment: Thanks, this might work. Well I used \d and \d\d etc for just example. If I need to parse with very long and different re, is there good way to write this code without just replacing re with variables? Also, another view point, using '|' expression is not easy to understand what this code is doing. If-else code makes me understand easily that the code switches behavior based on what written in each line.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor it's eager, you try to catch the most first, etc. As you can see from the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to perl except 'elif' instead of 'elsif' and ':' after the test and no curly braces (replaced by indentation) and optional parenthesis. There are many resources on the web which describe Python statements and more which can be easily found with a google search.

```
if re.search(r'(\d)', line):
    a = re.search(r'(\d)', line).group(1)
elif re.search(r'(\d\d)', line):
    b = re.search(r'(\d\d)', line).group(1)
elif re.search(r'(\d\d\d)', line):
    c = re.search(r'(\d\d\d)', line).group(1)
```

Of course the logic of the code is flawed since 'b' and 'c' never get set but I think this is the syntax you were looking for.

Comment: Please correct me if im' wrong but I think I can't retrieve value using res.group(1) if I use elif.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly because res isn't updated for each re.search call right? I need to do something like 'elif res = re.search(xx)' in each elif statement here but python doesn't allow me to write substitution in if statement.

Comment: Yes my first edit was not correct but the second edit does the trick. 'elif res = re.search(xx)' produces a syntax error because assignments are not also expressions as they are in C for example.

Comment: Problem here, is that you're re-evaluating each regex, which from a performance standpoint is bad